# How to get the current Latitude and Longitude values of the emulator device in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, mobile-emulator

Is there an option to find the location of the Emulator? I just need to plot the location of the device in the map.

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand your comment...Where did i put -ve??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator have had a build-in GPS simulator since May. Hopefully you updated your SDK since then (otherwise you should!). (Yes, you can use the *new* emulator with the 7.0 SDK and 7.0 apps!)

To access it, hover the mouse over the emulator, and click the **>>** button to the right.

[image]

Then press the *Location* tab, and voila, you can set the position with the build-in simulator.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Claus...This was very helpful !!..I have an other question now,how to work with real time device tracking?? Will the above settings help for that too ?

Comment: @Claus I've just downloaded all three items listed under WP 7.0 from here: http://create.msdn.com/en-us/resources/downloads and don't have the GPS option on my emulator.  Do you have a link to the resource that has it?

Comment: You're using the same APIs for both the emulator and a real-device, so a real-device would just give you the real-world coordinate, rather than the virtual one that you set in the emulator. - Regarding the tools, the `Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Beta 2` SDK that you can download, contains the GPS option on the emulator.

Comment: @Claus thought so, I'd at least put that in your answer as a beta is not really a "standard" SDK, Microsoft would be the first to say it's not production ready.

Comment: @Adam: Irrelevant. The emulator supports both the 7.0 SDK and the 7.1 -- and the 7.1 SDK haven't been possible to download for over 3 months!. And when that's said, the RTM is released tonight (the 22rd of August), and there been on API changes release Beta 1.

Comment: @Claus it's not irrelevant when the entire basis of the answer is not on the released version, but the future version.  The fact that the release is occurring tonight is just nice coincidence :-) but never mind.

Comment: @Adam Still wrong, this IS the released version. You **cannot** download the 7.0 SDK anymore. You misunderstood the entire developer experience with Windows Phone, if you thought that you weren't meant to upgrade before the RTM was released. (And I didn't ask him to download the Beta 2 Refresh that's only available on Microsoft Connect, which is the current beta-version)

Comment: @Claus I'm sorry, I just don't see it.  The tools to download from the MSDN home page is still 7.0.  At work I did this as soon as you mentioned the GPS emulator and it **doesn't** contain it.  At home I've got the beta SDK installed and it does, and as you say, old 7.0 projects use the new emulator - but I never disputed that.

Comment: @Claus as for misunderstanding the experience, last time I checked I didn't get any support for using beta software in production.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2744/discussion-between-claus-jorgensen-and-adam-houldsworth)

Comment: @Claus sorry, I would have joined the chat, but SO didn't give me a notification.

Answer (score -1):

we have to use static values for Emulator check with this URL 
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2010/03/22/geo-location-services-in-windows-phone-7-developer-emulator.aspx

we can use Windows Phone GPS Emulator (a small WPF application) check more details here 
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/01/28/windows-phone-gps-emulator.aspx

[image]